# remove characters up to a specific character AS column1, but also cast column1 as INT?

Tags: sql, casting

mycolumn is varchar. I need to removed characters up to and including '-', then cast that as an INT.

How do I CAST Column1 as an INT? I want the final result set to have Column1 as INT for later comparisons.

select right(mycolumn, len(mycolumn) - charindex('-', mycolumn)) AS Column1,
...

Comment: select CAST(right(mycolumn, len(mycolumn) - charindex('-', mycolumn)) AS INT)AS Column1

Comment: What DBMS?  There may be really easy ways to do this depending on your answer

Comment: Thank you, Sergey!
I am using MS SQL Server.